# Get date range for current view on Telerik RadScheduler

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

Is there a way to get the range of dates for the current view in a Telerik RadScheduler? SelectedView tells me whether I'm looking at month, week etc, but how do I find out which month/week etc I'm looking at? either that or a StartDate and EndDate woudl be good.

It would be good to know so I only load the relevant appointments from the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try VisibleRangeStart and VisibleRangeEnd

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/telerik.windows.controls.scheduler-telerik.windows.controls.radscheduler-visiblerangestart.html